# How can I extract data from a specific HTML link with html.parser in Python?

Tags: python, html, parsing, html-parsing

I have what I need for a very dumbed-down parser below. I'd like to create a method that takes in a URL to an HTML page (example: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/example) as a parameter and uses this parser to show me all of the data it encounters. I don't need somebody to give me the solution. However, advice would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def handle_data(self, data):
        print("Encountered some data  :", data)

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed('<html><head><title>Test</title></head>'
            '<body><h1>Parse me!</h1></body></html>')
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/urllib2.html#fetching-urls does it solve your problem?

Comment: That was pretty helpful. However, there have been a great deal of changes with that module since Python 2. I am using Python 3.6.1. If you're curious, check out my solution below. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up extracting data from a URL, in this case, http://python.org/.

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from urllib.request import urlopen

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_data(self, data):
        print("Encountered some data  :", data)

parser = MyHTMLParser()
html = urlopen('http://python.org/')
thing = html.read()
parser.feed(thing.decode("utf-8"))
```